# <a> inside <p> — it's a good practice in text cases?

Tags: html

**(✘)** I think this is wrong:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello!</li>
</ul>
```

**(✔)** And this is correct:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Hello!</p></li>
</ul>
```

But I don't know if this:

```
<ul>
    <li><p><a href="#">Hello!</a></p></li>
</ul>
```

Is more correct than this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello!</a></li>
</ul>
```

### My philosophy

I don't feel consistency when I work with texts outside `<p>` or `<h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6>`. I think that HTML is father of three types of text: **headers**, **paragraphs** & **tips**. For me, every text outside this pattern is wrong.

I'm here and now to know if it is **really wrong**. It is?

### Too abroad?

Sorry — I doesn't know another place better than SO for make this kind of question.

### Technically speaking...

Yes, I know that technically either way will work.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. "Can I put `<a>` inside `<p>` always that `<a>`"? What does that mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's a simple text"? It might be worth taking a moment to have someone else, more used to the English language, proof-read your question or, perhaps, rephrase your question.

Comment: Just a moment. I'll update the topic.

Comment: Look at your DTD, which tells you whether it’s allowed.

Comment: Guys, take a look in the new context now.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge you said `Yes, I know that I can, but look: `. But i cant see anything special there.

Comment: Take a look in my edition.

Comment: Each and every HTML example you post in your question is perfectly valid, and semantic, HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas All ways are correct, then?

Comment: You can decide whether you need to wrap `<a>` with `<p>` or not. Its according to your need. Everything you have written above is valid.

Comment: @Guilherme: yep, they're all fine (though, as noted in my answer, I'd argue *against* wrapping a single-word in a `p` tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (✘) I think this is wrong:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello!</li>
</ul>
```

No, that's perfectly correct.

> (✔) And this is correct:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Hello!</p></li>
</ul>
```

Yes, this is, *also*, correct.

The only difference is that, in the first example, you don't denote that the text is a paragraph, but merely a list-item; whereas in the second you show that it's a paragraph of text inside of a list-item. And, in this case, I'd be inclined to prefer the former (but it's purely a matter of taste and semantics), since I don't believe any single-word could ever constitute a whole paragraph all by itself.

> But I don't know if this:

```
<ul>
    <li><p><a href="#">Hello!</a></p></li>
</ul>
```

> Is more correct than this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello!</a></li>
</ul>
```

It makes no difference whatsoever.

You seem to feel a compulsion to wrap every string of text inside of an HTML element to denote its... *textiness*, which is unnecessary; certainly wrapping text inside of a `p` is only required if the text is, in fact, a paragraph.

Comment: True as I mentioned in my answer, the only difference will be the default value of the padding and margin of p. Nothing else..

Comment: PERFECT answer! That's exactly what I wanted! And yes, I think that I have something like a *compulsion* (what perfect term to describe what I feel inside!). Anyway, you and @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask whether it is legal or not, then yes it is legal.

However it is a better practice to include hyperlinks inside a paragraph if you're having a link inside the paragraph, there is no issue!

(Excluding **html5**) But you cannot start a whole paragraph inside a hyperlink, you can use div for that!

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello!</li>
</ul>
```

Above is correct, and so is:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Hello!</p></li>
</ul>
```

You can include anything inside a `li` that will include it inside a list. It has nothing to take only `a` or only `p`.

However this:

```
<ul>
    <li><p><a href="#">Hello!</a></p></li>
</ul>
```

Is different from

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello!</a></li>
</ul>
```

How? Because the `p` will add the margins and padding to the content. `p` has some default properties too.

Comment: Can I switch `<p>` into `<span>` if I don't want padding/margin? It's a correct way to think?

Comment: That will be ok! However, you can switch from `p` to `div` Because `div` is more close to `p` As div will start a new paragraph but span is just inline..

Comment: And at the same time, you can try this too: `p {margin: 0; padding: 0}` This will remove the margins and paddings..

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't start a `p` tag, inside an `a` tag, and close it outside the `a`.

Comment: I can't criticise your answer (because I don't understand the question), but can I ask what you think the question is..?

Comment: @DavidThomas i think i'm not getting it neither. This questions is really confusing. @Guilherme if you want to add only an `anchor` you can do that, you don't need to wrap it inside a `p` tag.

Comment: @N1KKou You got my question, but what I need to know if there's a "better practice" to display anchors.

Comment: There is no better practice in terms of wrapping an anchor, as the anchor has a `display` value of `inline`. It takes only the space between `a` tags. If it has no text content(or image), it wont occupy any space, and that's a bad practice. If you want it to take(for example) a full line, you can set his `display` css rule to `block`, and align the content as it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

## All HTML versions:

You cannot put `<a>` inside another `<a>`.

## All HTML versions, except HTML5:

Putting `<p>` into `<a>` is disallowed.